# Salesforce Apex - Populating an object from SOQL query

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, soql

I have a simple SOQL query that returns information relating to a Contact and CampaignMember. I'm attempting to populate a custom object with the results of the SOQL query. However I get the following error when loading the Visualforce page:

**Invalid field campaign.name for CampaignMember**

```
List campaignMembers = [select campaign.name, contact.id,contact.firstname, contact.lastname, status, campaignId from CampaignMember where contactId = '003U000000U0eNq' and  campaignId in :campaigns];

for (Integer i = 0; i < campaignMembers.size(); i++) {
    results.add(new CampaignMemberResult(
        (String)campaignMembers[i].get('CampaignId'), 
        (String)campaignMembers[i].get('campaign.name'),
        true
    ));
}
```

I've ran the SOQL query seperately in the Developer Console and it queries successfully. Why can I not pull in the campaign.name from the SOQL query within the for loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error you see is caused by the fact you should write it as `campaignMembers[i].Campaign.Name`. Or if you insist on the getter syntax, [`campaignMembers[i].getSobject('Campaign').get('Name')`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm).

Any special reason you need the wrapper object (or whatever `CampaignMemberResult` is)?
I have strange feeling you're writing too much code to achieve something simple ;) The syntax with `campaignMembers[i].Campaign.Name` will also mean you don't have to use casts to String.

---

Plus - if you need to know "*in which campaigns does this Contact occur*" you have 2 ways:

**flat**

```java
select contact.id,contact.firstname, contact.lastname, 
    campaignid, campaign.name, 
    status 
from CampaignMember 
where contactId = '003U000000U0eNq'
```

**subquery**

From contact you go down to the related list of campaignmembers, then up to campaigns to get their names

```java
SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName,
    (SELECT CampaignId, Campaign.Name FROM CampaignMembers)
FROM Contact WHERE Id = '003U000000U0eNq'
```

Example how to use "flat" result straight in visualforce (without `CampaignMemberResult`):

Apex:

```java
public List<CampaignMember> flatMembers {get;set;} // insert dick joke here

flatMembers = [select contact.id,contact.firstname, contact.lastname, 
    campaignid, campaign.name, 
    status 
from CampaignMember 
where contactId = '003U000000U0eNq'];
```

VF:

```java
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!flatMembers}" var="cm">
    <apex:column value="{!cm.Contact.LastName}" />
    <apex:column value="{!cm.Status}" />
    <apex:column value="{!cm.Campaign.Name}" />
```

---

**EDIT**

> My end goal is a Visualforce page to be displayed on the contact
>   record showing a list of all campaigns with a checkbox alongside each
>   indicating if the contact is a member or not.

You do realize it can quickly grow into a pretty long table? Maybe some filter on campaigns (if you feel like reading about sth advanced - check the documentation for "StandardSetController"). Also I'm pretty sure there are some ways to add Contacts/Leads to Campaigns from Campaign reports - maybe something out of the box would save your time and be more maintainable...

But code solution would be pretty straightforward, start with a helper wrapper class:

```java
public class CampaignWrapper{
    public Boolean selected {get;set;}
    public Campaign c {get; private set;}
    public CampaignWrapper(Campaign c){
        this.c = c;
        selected = !c.CampaignMembers.isEmpty();
    }
}
```

Then a query and build the list of wrappers:

```java
List<CampaignWrapper> wrappers = new List<CampaignWrapper>();
for(Campaign c : [SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id FROM CampaignMember WHERE ContactId = '...')
    FROM Campaign
    LIMIT 1000]){
    wrappers.add(new CampaignMember(c));
}
```

You should be all set ;) If it's just for displaying - you might not even need the wrapper class (some tricks in visualforce expressions maybe or use `Map<Campaign, Boolean>` even...

1000 records is the limit of collections passed to Visualforce (10K if your page will be readonly). Past that - pagination, most likely with use with abovementioned StandardSetController.

Comment: Thanks eyescream, I think you are right in thinking I'm writing too much code for something simple. My end goal is a Visualforce page to be displayed on the contact record showing a list of all campaigns with a checkbox alongside each indicating if the contact is a member or not. Using your example above with some tweaks, I thing this should be possible?

Comment: Thanks eyescream, as usual your answers are a great insight!

Comment: Hi eyescream, I've updated my controller to use the pattern that you have described above in your edit. I had to update the line were we add new CampaignMembers from wrappers.add(new CampaignMember(c)); to wrappers.add(new CampaignMember(Campaign=c)); as I had a compile error. However, I now have the following compile error relating to the wrapper class:

Incompatible element type SOBJECT:CampaignMember for collection of CampaignMailingGroupController.CampaignWrapper.

My wrapper class sits inside my main controller class, is this correct?

Comment: I'm surprised you had to use something as weird as `Campaign=c`. I mean it's like saying `Integer=5`, does it even compile? Can you maybe edit your question with a bigger code snippet? Both the wrapper class def. and the query you use to populate the list...

Comment: I though it was strange as I was writing it, but it compiled?? Anyway I've since seen the error of my ways and reverted the change. I am now adding (new Campaign(c)); to the wrappers list, and the result is exactly what I'm after! Thanks again for the help.